# Update one column based on the no of values in another column

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

My dataframe goes thru different `methods` and gets updated.
In each `method`, the new values are added to `ErrorCode` , `ErrorColVal` and `ErrorColName` columns.

This is my initial dataframe.

```
+--------+-----------------+-----------+--------------------+
|sequence|        ErrorCode|ErrorColVal|        ErrorColName|
+--------+-----------------+-----------+--------------------+
|       1|CHAR0008-CHAR0021|X-SAHU     |X-LASTNAME          |
|       2|CHAR0009-CHAR0021|SAMBIT-SAHU|FIRSTNAME-LASTNAME  |
|       3|CHAR0009         |SANTOSH    |FIRSTNAME           |
|       5|CHAR0009         |SANTOSH    |FIRSTNAME           |
|       8|CHAR0009-CHAR0021|SAMBIT-SAHU|FIRSTNAME-LASTNAME  |
+--------+-----------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

In some `methods` what happens is - only one value is added to `ErrorCode` but more than one values are added to `ErrorColVal` and `ErrorColName`.

In this case for `sequence = 2`,
The `ErrorColName` is updated with two values i.e. `SURNAME` and `TITLE`.
The `ErrorColVal` is updated with two values i.e. `SINGH` and `DR`.
But `ErrorCode` is updated with only one value i.e. `CHAR0022`.

The dataframe is like below now.

```
+--------+--------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------+
|sequence|                 ErrorCode|         ErrorColVal|                    ErrorColName|
+--------+--------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------+
|       1|CHAR0008-CHAR0021-CHAR0022|X-SAHU-SINGH        |X-LASTNAME-SURNAME-TITLE        |
|       2|CHAR0009-CHAR0021-CHAR0022|SAMBIT-SAHU-SINGH-DR|FIRSTNAME-LASTNAME-SURNAME-TITLE|
|       3|CHAR0009                  |SANTOSH             |FIRSTNAME                       |
|       5|CHAR0009                  |SANTOSH             |FIRSTNAME                       |
|       8|CHAR0009-CHAR0021-CHAR0022|SAMBIT-SAHU-BORA    |FIRSTNAME-LASTNAME-SURNAME      |
+--------+--------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------+
```

This could lead to uncertainty down the line.
As, we can not determine what is the corresponding `ErrorColVal` and `ErrorColName` for `ErrorCode=CHAR0022` for `sequence=2`.

I need to correct this kind of mismatch by repeating the same `ErrorCode` again.
At any point of time, all the three column should have similar number of values..

Please consider the value `CHAR0022` is available to me in field `ErrCd` and I can do `lit("ErrCd")`.
The challenge is to find out, number of values in `ErrorColVal` and `ErrorColName` dynamically and update `ErrorCode` accordingly.
Can we write a `method` for this to reuse again and again.

The output dataframe is going to look like below:

```
+--------+-----------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------+
|sequence|                          ErrorCode|         ErrorColVal|                    ErrorColName|
+--------+-----------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------+
|       1|CHAR0008-CHAR0021-CHAR0022         |X-SAHU-SINGH        |X-LASTNAME-SURNAME-TITLE        |
|       2|CHAR0009-CHAR0021-CHAR0022-CHAR0022|SAMBIT-SAHU-SINGH-DR|FIRSTNAME-LASTNAME-SURNAME-TITLE|
|       3|CHAR0009                           |SANTOSH             |FIRSTNAME                       |
|       5|CHAR0009                           |SANTOSH             |FIRSTNAME                       |
|       8|CHAR0009-CHAR0021-CHAR0022         |SAMBIT-SAHU-BORA    |FIRSTNAME-LASTNAME-SURNAME      |
+--------+-----------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Could you please help me in achieving the same.

Thank you.

Comment: I started writing out a suggestion but I don't think there's an easy way to do this. It's going to involve mapping between a code and the number of possible values and then doing like a greedy search to find what it _could_ be but even then, the more complicated your codes get you are going to have a hard time. The easier way to do this would be to use a separate delimiter when 2 values are added like `SAMBIT-SAHU-SINGH|DR`. I know this probably doesn't help if you already have a lot of this data but this would have been a better way to gather this data.

Comment: Thank you @KenMyers for your input, I will try the idea of different delimiter and see how it goes.

Comment: @KenMyers, your idea of using a different delimiter is working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: That's great! Glad it is working for you!